# How to make the name centered with addresses on either side in res.cls

Tags: horizontal-alignment, resume

I am using a resume template here: http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/res9b.tex

cls:
http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/res.cls

I was wondering how to make the name centered with addresses on either side but I cannot figure out how to use this cls document which seems to have a way to do it but I still cant figure it out. Any suggestions? Here is the code I found in the cls.

```
% prints a centered name with the address centered
% or the two address on opposite sides of the page
%
\def\@printcentername{\begingroup
  % print the name centered
  \leavevmode\hbox to \textwidth{\hfil\@tablebox{\namefont\@name}\hfil}\par
  \@ifundefined{@addressone}{%
    % do nothing
  }{%
    \@ifundefined{@addresstwo}{
      % only one address
      \leavevmode\hbox to \textwidth{\hfil\@tablebox{\@addressone}\hfil}\par
    }{
      % two addresses
      \leavevmode\hbox to \textwidth{\@tablebox{\@addressone}\hfil
                     \@tablebox{\@addresstwo}}\par
    }%
  }%
\endgroup}
```

---

There is also this code I just found, but again how to use it is a mystery to me. I want option 1:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% HEADINGS:
% There are two types of headings:
% 1) one with the name centered and the address centered or
%    in the left and right side if there are two address
% 2) one where the name is in the upper left corner 
%    the a line accross the paper
%    then the address all on one line in the right corner
%    the second address will be directly below the first if defined
%
\let\print@name\relax
\def\ds@centered{\ifx\print@name\relax\let\print@name\@printcentername\fi}
\def\ds@line{\ifx\print@name\relax\let\print@name\@linename\fi}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I'm actually an old user, Google reset my stats because I added a new gmail to my account

Comment: Never mind, Welcome back :) Not related but, Did you have a look at [moderncv](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv) which might have more flexibility

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by enabling the `centered` option on the document:

`\documentclass[margin,centered]{resume}`

This centers your name on a line by itself, and uses both sides of the next few lines for your address.

If you'd like your name to be on the same line in between the two addresses, you can modify the `printcentername` method to be this:

```
\def\@printcentername{\begingroup
  % print the name centered
  %\leavevmode\hbox to \textwidth{\hfil\@tablebox{\namefont\@name}\hfil}\par
  \@ifundefined{@addressone}{%
    % do nothing
  }{%
    \@ifundefined{@addresstwo}{
      % only one address
      \leavevmode\hbox to \textwidth{\hfil\@tablebox{\@addressone}\hfil}\par
    }{
      % two addresses
      \leavevmode\hbox to \textwidth{\@tablebox{\@addressone}\hfil
                     \@tablebox{\namefont\@name}\hfil % Center name in between addresses
                     \@tablebox{\@addresstwo}}\par
    }%
  }%
\endgroup}
```

Comment: You need to use `centered` as the document class option. `center` is not defined (even though the "documentation" mentions this). Regardless, the default option is to have the details `centered`.

Comment: That's right, thanks! I've updated my answer.